# How to build jar with enclosed Javadoc? In one step?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc

I am using IntelliJ Idea to create a Java Jar library, works great.

It also has Javadoc compliant comments but when I integrate the Jar to another project I can't access the doc?

Is it possible to build that Jar and Javadoc in one step?

Thanks

Comment: Why? The JAR file is for deployment to execution environments. The Javadoc is for developers. Not the same people.

Comment: Usually the docs are packaged into a separate JAR. The other project needs to integrate both JARs, but in different ways: one as classes, another one as javadoc. Modern IDEs handle it well. Now, building *both* JARs in one step would make sense, although I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: As far as I know, it's possible to [create javadocs from IJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/generating-javadoc-reference-for-a-project.html) but not in the same step with the artifact. However this should be possible with [maven](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/), [gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.Javadoc.html), etc which integrate nicely with IJ